# Sling resolution jsp priority

Tags: components, aem, sling

My scenario is the following

```
Component A
 main.jsp 
 other.jsp
```

Other.jsp is included in main.jsp

Component B needs to be implemented in sightly, and I need the have another implementation for other.jsp, but main.jsp stays the same in Component B. 
Properties:

```
sling:resourceSuperType=Component A
sling:resourceType= Component B
```

I have to mention that component A is already implemented. Which is the best aproach?

Comment: Can you please add more information or at least describe the node structure/properties of your components? from this question we can do nothing but speculate.

Comment: My scenario would be... I have component A, with 2 scripts main.jsp and other.jsp. Other.jsp is included in main.jsp, . Component B need to be implemented in sightly, and I need the have another implementation for other.jsp, but main.jsp stays the same in Component B. I have to mention that component A is already implemented. Which is the best aproach? Thx

Comment: Please add that to the question, along with all sling properties used and their values.

Comment: I have added the requested info to the question

Comment: It's not clear to be how Component B would look like and what the relation is between Component A and Component B. Do you want to override some behaviour from Component A (JSP) with Component B (HTL)?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this structure:

```
Component A
    main.jsp
    other.jsp

Component B - sling:resourceSuperType=Component A
    main.jsp
```

In this case, main.jsp of B will override main.jsp of A.  But since B doesn't have its own other.jsp, the other.jsp of A would be used if it is referenced.

It sounds like you have created **main.html** to try to override **main.jsp**.  To override you need it to be a **JSP** with the same name.  See also scenario 2 of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16120322/230055

Comment: My scenario would be... I have component A, with 2 scripts main.jsp and other.jsp. Other.jsp is included in main.jsp, . Component B need to be implemented in sightly, and I need the have another implementation for other.jsp, but main.jsp stays the same in Component B. I have to mention that component A is already implemented. Which is the best aproach? Thx

Comment: Then component B should have the sling:resourceSuperType set to A, but it should only have an other.jsp.  That way, the main.jsp will use the one from A, but the other.jsp will use the one from A.  If you find this override doesn't work, it could be that main.jsp in A is referencing other.jsp in A using an absolute path.  If you make that a relative path then you will get the override needed.